# IIS Stops Responding after Application Pool Recycle

Tags: iis

I'm running an ASP.NET MVC application on Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8.5. This morning, users started complaining that our site was down. Logging onto the server I noticed no noticeable memory or CPU pressure being experienced, and restarting the website in IIS resolved the issue.

Looking into the IIS logs I noticed that at around 23:00 is when requests started degrading in performance. At the same time, only certain requests appear to be logged here as successful. All other request to the server are not logged here at all.

I can see our pingdom monitoring was successfully calling our uptime page and getting a successful response, but no other client requests appear to have been successful.

Checking the httperr log I can see all my other requests appear to be failing with the error Connection_Dropped during this period. The issue seems to have started occurring at exactly 23:00 - which is when the application pool recycled.

There are no other errors in our event logs, no application level errors either, so I'm just wondering what other logs could I could potentially look into here to see why requests appear to stop going through to IIS?

Comment: any other proxies  ARR / haProxy involved in your setup?

Comment: @Matt Nothing out of the ordinary like that, and this is the first time we've experienced something like this. No major changes to how things work or how it is hosted either.

Comment: Is your worker process actually running? Is you Pingdom page static, or one that would actually use this worker process?

Comment: @MatthewEvans The pingdom page exercises the db, and returns a very basic html page. So IIS is definitely running, I can see it returning static files etc.